# NHibernate No Physical Deletion

Tags: nhibernate

My problem is that NHibernate would not physically delete data (such as images) from the database, although the log says that a DELETE command has been issued - the file size remains the same.

I am using NHibernate.3.3.1.4000 and FluentNHibernate.1.4.0.0. Updating to newer versions is not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem can be solved by using the SQL statement VACUUM.